# How to inline-block in <IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to show some rating stars, which are aligned as repeated images with `inline-block` as follows:

```
<span class="stars" style="width:20px; margin-top:15px;">
    <span style="width:40px;"></span>
</span>

span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/stars.png) 0 0px repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gwtd1rLc/1/

Problem: inline-block, thus the images are not shown properly.

Question: how could I refactor it so that it works in all/most browsers?

Comment: I've flagged a duplicate; the accepted answer there will give you the solution for IE7 and possibly IE6. But seriously... do you *really* still need to support people using IE7 and IE6? Really??

Comment: Yes, I need to support :(

Comment: Basically no one is using IE6 and IE7 anymore.. And if they do, it is their problem. If you support IE8, that should be good enough.

Comment: It's not because we show the webpage embedded inside a tool, and inside there is an embedded old web browser that behaves like <IE8. So I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for < IE8

```
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Comment: And how would I add this only for <IE8?

Comment: Use a conditional stylesheet. Although it should be noted including this won't break anything newer. See the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: you don't need a conditional stylesheet. The stars at the start of the lines there are an IE-specific hack (the syntax is invalid CSS but IE<8 recognises it anyway, so the styles are therefore only applied in IE<8; this is a well-known hack for this kind of thing)

Comment: @membersound Simba is right,just add it to your css element